# How to get data based on keywords

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query having columns Created By, Date, LogAgent, Logcomments like this.

```
Select createdby,Date,LogAgent,Logcomments from ticketsdata where ticketnumber='123456'
```

If I give like this I am getting data like below.
But I need only the row where I have 'Resolved' to 'Closed'

```
+-----------+------------+----------+-------------------------------------------------+ 
| createdby |  Date      | LogAgent | Logcomments                            
+-----------+------------+----------+-------------------------------------------------+
| AAAAA     | 12/02/2013 | Ramu     | Status changed from 'Resolved' to 'Closed'      |
| AAAAA     | 12/02/2013 | Ramu     | Status changed from 'Researching' to 'Resolved' |
| AAAAA     | 12/02/2013 | Ramu     | Status changed from 'Hold' to 'Researching'     |
| AAAAA     | 12/02/2013 | Ramu     | Status changed from 'Open' to 'Hold'
+-----------+------------+----------+-------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Please learn to format your posts after almost 50 questions!!!!

Comment: **`LIKE`** ? Or if `Logcomments` column values are standardised like this then use it directly

Comment: Like I am getting the data as i Mentioned in my question.For same ticket I am getting many rows.But I want the row where its having 'Resolved' to 'Closed' in logcomments

Comment: @MaciejLos Subtle single quotes in the data which will not be found by your sql

Comment: where ticketnumber='123456' AND Logcomments Like %'''Resolved'' to ''Closed'''%

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please try this

**Table Creation and Data Generation -**

```
CREATE TABLE t2
(
     ticketnumber  VARCHAR(100)
    ,[createdby]  VARCHAR(100)
    ,[Date] DATE
    ,LogAgent  VARCHAR(100)
    ,Logcomments VARCHAR(MAX)
)
GO

INSERT INTO T2 VALUES
('123456','AAAAA','12/02/2013','Ramu','Status changed from ''Resolved'' to ''Closed'''),
('123456','AAAAA','12/02/2013','Ramu','Status changed from ''Researching'' to ''Resolved'''),
('123456','AAAAA','12/02/2013','Ramu','Status changed from ''Hold'' to ''Researching'''),
('123456','AAAAA','12/02/2013','Ramu','Status changed from ''Open'' to ''Hold''')
GO
```

**SOLUTION**

```
select * from T2
where ticketnumber='123456' AND Logcomments Like '%''Resolved'' to ''Closed''%'
```

**OUTPUT**

```
/*------------------------
select * from T2
where ticketnumber='123456' AND Logcomments Like '%''Resolved'' to ''Closed''%'
------------------------*/
ticketnumber                    createdby   Date       LogAgent    Logcomments
------------------------------- ----------- ---------- ----------- ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
123456                          AAAAA       2013-12-02 Ramu        Status changed from 'Resolved' to 'Closed'

(1 row(s) affected)
```

Comment: how is this different than the other answer here ?

Answer (score 0):

@Ganesh answare is correct And here is the test :

```
Declare @table table (
    createdby varchar(50),
    Dates datetime,
    LogAgent varchar(50),
    Logcomments nvarchar(max)
)

insert into @table 
select 'AAAAA', '12/02/2013', 'Ramu', 'Status changed from ''Resolved'' to ''Closed''' union
select 'AAAAA', '12/02/2013', 'Ramu', 'Status changed from ''Researching'' to ''Resolved''' union
select 'AAAAA', '12/02/2013', 'Ramu', 'Status changed from ''Hold'' to ''Researching''' union
select 'AAAAA', '12/02/2013', 'Ramu', 'Status changed from ''Open'' to ''Hold''' union
select 'BBBBB', '12/02/2013', 'TOTO', 'Status changed from ''Resolved'' to ''Closed''' 


Select *
from @table 
where Logcomments like  '%''Resolved'' to ''Closed''%'
```

here is the result :

[image]

Answer (score -1):

```
Select createdby,Date,LogAgent,Logcomments 
from ticketsdata 
where ticketnumber='123456'
and Logcomments like  '%''Resolved'' to ''Closed''%'
```

You can use the above query

Comment: this query seems to work, dont know why it gets downvoted

Comment: but already perfect answer in comment so why need put in new answer?